# How to use GDB on AMD64 UBUNTU with Docker on ARM systems

Tags: docker, ubuntu, arm, gdb, x86-64

Hi I'm studying pwnable

For various reasons I need to install X86_64 Ubuntu on my m1 (ARM architecture) mac.

I used docker to install it.
The command to run docker is below
`docker run -v ~/Downloads/315bf023-2515-486c-9785-b49a295d94b4:/tmp/ --platform linux/amd64 -it --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE ubuntu:x86_64`

But the problem is that gdb is not working properly.
If I do it normally (using gdb on an X86_64 system), I set a breakpoint, run it, and it stops at the breakpoint and pops up the debugging screen, but if I run it as shown in the photo below, it doesn't work at all...
The picture is using pwndbg, but I don't think the behavior is different from normal dbg.
[gdb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf1NL.png)

The log looks like this

```
root@4f403c5cd1f0:/tmp# cat gdb.txt
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080485cc <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080485cd <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080485cf <+3>: add    esp,0xffffff80
   0x080485d2 <+6>: call   0x8048572 <initialize>
   0x080485d7 <+11>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x80]
   0x080485da <+14>:    push   eax
   0x080485db <+15>:    call   0x80483d0 <gets@plt>
   0x080485e0 <+20>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x080485e3 <+23>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080485e8 <+28>:    leave
   0x080485e9 <+29>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485cf
Starting program: /tmp/basic_exploitation_001
root@4f403c5cd1f0:/tmp#
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

I've been tinkering with Docker's launch options on the internet.
I've been tinkering with Docker's launch options on the internet.
So the final run command is
`docker run -v ~/Downloads/315bf023-2515-486c-9785-b49a295d94b4:/tmp/ --platform linux/amd64 -it --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE ubuntu:x86_64`
but that didn't work either.

Comment: upload gdp logs as the plain text format , images can be reproduced

Comment: Sorry, but the particular reason I posted the picture was to show that interactions like ni or ^C as stdin don't work.
Thanks for pointing that out, I take your feedback on board and will fix the post.

Comment: That stuff including `ni` and `^C` is just text on your terminal, and there isn't even any colour highlighting in that part, just the `pwngdb>` prompts.  Copy/pasting it from your terminal into a code block would capture exactly the same information as an image.  (i.e. the reader is still left to assume you pressed ctrl-C, not actually typed caret (^) and then capital C.)

Comment: i haven't found a way to get pwngdb working for docker under a MacOS arm arch, what i usually do in docker is run `valgrind -q --vgdb-error=0 <path-to-binary-to-debug>` then in parallel `gdb <path-to-binary-to-debug>` and in gdb `target remote |vgdb` then you can set breakpoints, inspect the registers, stack etc. It really helps tu use a terminal multiplexer (i.e. tmux), and i'm not even sure it's possible to do it without one.